# Session information being lost, seemingly at random

Tags: php, session

I will try to keep this as short as possible, and therefore not lose too much time going into detail about the security of my application, and stick to the techniques that seem to cause problem:

On my domain, I have people add items to a shopping cart which is stored in the php $_SESSION variable. Once they submit a form with their personal information (also stored in the $_SESSION) they get redirected to a payment service provider on a different domain (same window) with the payment details hashed with a secret key as POST values. Once the payment is verified and completed, users get redirected to a success page (back on my domain), where the shopping cart is transferred from the $_SESSION to the database, thereby becoming a placed order.

Having tested this on multiple machines, networks and browser types extensively, I thought this method to be sound. Yet some orders have been placed empty, with a new session_id.

It would be logical to assume that this happens because of a session timeout, yet the timeout on the payment is 15 minutes, where the timeout on the cart is 20 minutes. Also, I have seen this happen when the transaction was completed well within aforementioned periods (ie 1 minute).

Conclusion:
The session data was lost upon either
   - leaving my domain for the domain of the payment service provider, or
   - returning to my domain from the payment service provider

And more importantly: this only happens to a certain portion of the users, so by the looks of it this is a client side problem.

What am I missing here? Thanks in advance.

Comment: DO NOT use session to hold this kind of sensitive data in this case, properly make a database table to hold on progress orders, this will also allow you to verify people abusing from your system since you will have the records. If per chance the order comes back safely then either change it status from progress to paid or anything else or simple sent the tryout data into the actual order table. Yes, your session will only be usable on your domain only and not on 3rd parties.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Prix, I have already leaned towards this solution, yet could use advice how I am to decide which order to update to paid from pending? The payment service provider does not pass any kind of identifier related to the client upon redirecting to my domain. This is why I went with sessions, comparing order with received payment before actually sending the product to prevent misuse.

And I know sessions are only available to the domain they are created on, that's not an issue here.

Comment: Probably the session cookie is lost on the client side. You have to move the order from the session into the database before payment...